# Why do a div and a button with the same styles render at different sizes?

Tags: html, css

I have a page with some clickable `<div>` elements, and I want to change them to `<button>`s instead to make it easier to identify them via jQuery. But when I change the `<div>`s to `<button>`s, their size changes. (I'm styling them as fixed width and height, but the button renders at a different width and height than the div does.)

Here's a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/AjmGY/

Here's my CSS:

```css
.styled {
    border: 4px solid black;
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="styled"></div>
<button class="styled"></button>
```

I would expect to see two boxes of identical size, but the bottom box (the `<button>`) is noticeably smaller. This behavior is consistent across all the browsers I tried it on, both Windows (Chrome, FireFox, IE, Opera) and Android (built-in browser and Dolphin).

I tried adding `display: block;` to the style, thinking that that might make them both render using the same rules (i.e., make the `button` render like a `div` since it's a block element now), but that had no effect -- the button remained smaller.

As I increase the border width, the disparity increases. It looks as though the button's `border` is *inside* its `width`, rather than above and beyond its `width` as with the `<div>`. As far as I understand it, this violates the [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), though the W3C does say:

> [user agents may render borders for certain user interface elements (e.g., buttons, menus, etc.) differently than for "ordinary" elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-properties).

Is it normal / documented / expected behavior for a `button` to have its border on the inside of its width and height, rather than outside? Can I rely on this behavior?

(My page uses an HTML5 doctype, if that's relevant.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Buttons and other input controls are rendered using the [border-box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing) by default; i.e. content, padding and border all add up to the total `width` that you declare. They also often have some padding added by browsers arbitrarily according to their default stylesheets. As you quote, this is acceptable behavior and not a violation of standards; it's simply to accommodate rendering of OS-level GUI controls.

To get your `button` to be the same size as your `div`, size it according to the content-box model (which is "the" original W3C box model) and zero out its padding:

```
button.styled {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AjmGY/4)

Comment: Can you rely on this behavior to be consistent? I don't know if you can, but I won't if I'm customizing my controls.