# Understanding why input element and <a> element are different sizes with the same CSS settings

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue trying to understand why different html elements have different end results with the same settings. Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hovpG/) showing the issue. I'm trying to get the links to look like the buttons.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395349/why-do-a-div-and-a-button-with-the-same-styles-render-at-different-sizes?rq=1)

Comment: @mseifert Thanks this was driving me crazy.